# Power BI, find the lowest value in the future

Tags: excel, powerbi

I'm trying to re-create an available stock calculation in Power BI that I have been able to do in Excel.

Shows the table and formula for column M

[image: Shows the table and formula for column M]

Basically, the (weekly) available stock is current (or starting) stock minus cumulative orders plus cumulative production, i.e. column K is column H-I+J.

I have been able to re-create columns G-K in Power BI, however column M is a trickier one.

As seen in the screen shot, column M is calculated by taking the MIN of the Available Stock for current or any future week. The formula is not anchored, so the formula in M3 is MIN(K3:143) M4 is MIN(K4:K144) and so on.

It would be extremely useful to have this calculation in Power BI as well, but have been unsuccessful thus far. If it helps, columns H, I, J and K are Measures in Power BI.

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way:

```
Availablilty = 
    CALCULATE( MIN('Table'[Available Stock]),
        Filter('Table','Table'[Week no] >= EARLIEST('Table'[Week no])))
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This works when I have one product in the table, however it doesn't when I have 2 or more. Do you know what to add to the formula for it to distinguish between the product codes (at the moment all products have the same values). Thanks in advance.